# Incremento de dos dias por cada mes trabajado

Tags: php

Tengo una tabla de `usuarios` en una BD, donde tengo los siguientes campos:

```
id_ususario
login
passwd
dias_disponibles (Los usuarios fijos tienen 24 días disponibles)
fecha_ingreso (Fecha ingreso en empresa)
tipo_usuario (Fijo o Temporal)
```

Cada usuario puede hacer una solicitud de vacaciones. El usuario `admin` es el que se encarga de añadir los nuevos usuarios. Mi problema está con los usuarios `temporales`. Un usuario temporal tendrá los días disponibles según los meses trabajados hasta un año. Por cada mes trabajado, `dias_disponibles` se le incrementa en 2. Por ejemplo, si `usuario1` desde que ingresó en la empresa, lleva 2 meses trabajados pues tendrá 4 `dias_disponibles` y así sucesivamente hasta que lleve 12 meses, entonces a partir de ahí, serán siempre 24 `dias_disponibles`.
Tengo esta función que me calcula la diferencia de meses desde que ingresó en la empresa hasta hoy:

```
function difmeses($fechaingreso){
$fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso);

$fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
$fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);

$diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

$meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;

return $meses;
}
```

Mi duda es qué utilizar para que se vaya incrementando hasta que lleve 12 meses en la empresa, si lleva 12 meses se para. Alguna ayuda de como hacer el incremento de 2 dias, un `for`, un `while`...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes cambiar el return de la función de la siguiente manera:

```
function difmeses($fechaingreso){
    $fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso);

    $fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);
    $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

    $meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;

    return $meses > 12? 12:$meses;
}
```

De esta manera si meses es menor que 12 te va a devolver el valor que correponde, de lo contrario siempre devuelve 12.

[Aca](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5101e6d49f0ed501b703ff9ad408bd01eb588132) te dejo un sandbox con la prueba

**EDIT**

Con respecto a tu comentario, se me ocurre que podes hacer algo asi:

primero traes todos los usuarios `select * from sec_users`, luego recorres con un for la totalidad de usuarios y le aplicas  una funcion que calcule los días disponibles y luego updateas el campo `dias_disponibles` del usuario.

Aca un seudocodigo para que se vea mejor:

```
$usuarios <- "select * from sec_users"

foreach($usuarios as $usuario){
    $usuario["dias_disponibles"] = calcularDias($usuario["fecha_ingreso"])
    -> update sec_users set dias_disponibles = $usuario["dias_disponibles"] where id_usuario = $usuario["id_usuario"];
}
```

Y la función `calcularDias` devolvería los días que le corresponden a ese usuario, seria igual a la función difmeses, solo multiplicando el resultado por dos.

```
function calcularDias($fechaingreso){
    $fechainicial = new DateTime($fechaingreso);

    $fechaactual = (new DateTime)->format('Y-m-d H:i');
    $fechafinal = new DateTime($fechaactual);
    $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);

    $meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;

    return ($meses > 12? 12:$meses)*2;
}
```

Comment: Eso me es de gran ayuda! La verdad es que no había caído en eso. Mi pregunta es como pongo la formula para incrementar, un `for`? un `while`?

Comment: @Xerox, No entiendo bien tu consulta, en que contexto esta usando esta funcion?

Comment: La función que tu me has puesto de ejemplo está bien. Me da la diferencia de meses. Pero ahora quiero crear un bucle, en el que utilizando esa función, me incremente en 2 los dias disponibles de cada usuario, cada vez que haya trabajado un mes. Me explico, si usuario1 ha trabajado 2 meses pues tendrá 4 días disponibles, si ha trabajado 3 meses pues tendrá 6 dias disponibles y así sucesivamente. Mi problema es que nosé que bucle utilizar

Comment: Por ejemplo, un bucle que utilice la función que he creado y cuando compruebe que ha pasado un mes pues que sume 2 dias a dias disponibles con este sql:

`update sec_users set dias_disponibles=dias_disponibles+2 where login = 'usuario1'`

Answer (score 0):

La solución más natural quizá sea utilizar una tarea cron en linux, o tarea programada en windows, que ataque a una url específica con un proceso php que haga el cambio en la base de datos tras revisar que las condiciones son correctas.

Otra posible solución sería crear un proceso trigger en mysql programado cada mes que realizase una consulta de select y un insert en función de esta.

Comment: Sí, pero más bien preferiría hacer el incremento con un for o un while y utilizar también el update de sql para incrementar los días